# How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP with full Links?

Tags: php, html, dom, hyperlink

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://URL");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

But there is a problem with intern links on the server

is it possible to transform th /css file //css file to www.domain.com/css,  www.domain.com//css without changing the position in the code

Comment: You can do it yourself using `str_replace` or by other methods. It would be easy to do so.